# non english characters are displaying ???? in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, php

I'm working on an application using PHP, JavaScript and Ajax. My application works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but not in Internet Explorer.

Details:

I am translating my content into Arabic and Russian and displaying it in the text fields. When I try to post the values of the text fields with JavaScript and Ajax using the GET method then it shows ????? instead of the values for Arabic and Russian. All of my pages contain:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I have saved the `.js` file with UTF-8 encoding. It contains this code:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","save_banner2.php?b1="+banner1+"&b2="+banner2, true);
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried <?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>

Comment: If your getting data from MySQL database try to set the characters set  for the connection like $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: Internet Explorer does not automatically encode the URL you pass into XMLHTTP, unlike in other browsers. So the right approach is to encode the data yourself, as Abe suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using [encodeURIComponent](http://blog.bobpeers.com/2009/06/05/xmlhttp-utf-8-and-foreign-characters/):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","save_banner2.php?b1="+encodeURIComponent(banner1)+"&b2="+encodeURIComponent(banner2), true);
```

Comment: *Content-Type* has no purpose in a GET request.

Comment: @Gumbo OK, then I'll try a different approach

Answer (score 0):

You have to examine

```
Content-Type: ...; charset=utf-8
```

header in your server response. It has to contain the right encoding, which always takes precedence over `<meta>` tag.